# warning in xml.tree in openpyxl

Tags: openpyxl

I am using openpyxl from different Python version using following way.

> sys.path.insert(0,
>   '/remote/Python-2.7.2-shared/linux32/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl-1.6.1-py2.7.egg')
>
> sys.path.insert(1,
>   '/remote/Python-2.7.2-shared/linux32/lib/python2.7/site-packages')

I will not receive any warning when I directly use particular version.

> Python-2.7.2-shared/linux32/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/openpyxl/shared/compat/elementtree.py:30:
>   UserWarning: Unable to import 'xml.etree.cElementree'. Falling back on
>   'xml.etree.Elementree'

I am reading more than 100 xlsx File and did manual testing previously and need to provide quick fix.

As per my understanding, I am reading xlsx File and does not contain any xml element. 
So it should  not impact any reading data in xlsx File. **can be confirm it or can I ignore this warning.**

One small thing not related to openpyxl.

> is it possible to hide this warning. I do not have root permission

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore warnings. What you are doing is not recommended. The warning is just that without cElementTree your code may run slow. Python does support install packages for in user home directories but using virtual environments (virtualenv) is preferable.